# I made a mistake by assign the pd.read_csv to a variable how to fix this

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import, python-import

The code was like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
    
variable=pd.read_csv=("filename.csv")
```

Instead of:

```py
variable=pd.read_csv("filename.csv" )
```

The error is:

```
'str' object is not callable
```

I tried to change the variable but still the same errors occur. I think the problem in the function because I assign it to variable so the function became a string.

I tried to call the function in a new notebook and it worked.

But I want the function to work on the same notebook I work in, so how to fix it?

Comment: remove the offending line and restart your notebook

Comment: Are you using some sort of IDE? Then you could exit and re-enter.

Comment: THAT code could not have caused THAT error.  You must have done something like `pd = "Hello"`, which lost the original definition of `pd`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to restart your notebook, you can reload the `pandas` library using [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload):

```
variable=pd.read_csv=("filename.csv")
# oops!
variable=pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

from importlib import reload
reload(pd)

variable=pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
# success! :)
```